# what should I do with 2 main function in libsvm for c#

Tags: c#, libsvm

I want to use libsvm for a classification task in c# 
but it's files contains 2 main function and my program have one too.so it cause erorr:"has more one entry point defined"
how can I fix it? should I delete other main function or what?
tanks

Comment: If these main methods are in the different classes, you can specify "Startup object"; open assembly property window, "application" tab and select required class for the "Startup object:"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should delete any one of your Main function. As .Net framework allows only one entry point per .EXE. Entry point is nothing but Mani function.